# Ensuring entity framework migration sequence

Tags: entity-framework

What is the best practice with dealing with EF migrations in a team environment? How can you ensure that people branching and merging code actually commit their migrations in correct sequence? How would you go about making sure the migrations are applied in the order they were merged into the release branch? Is that something team members have to deal with manually or can you leverage your build server to do automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to find an article on how to deal with merging migrations properly: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481501(v=vs.113).aspx